# SSRS Select NULL values in two different parameters

Tags: sql, reporting-services

1st ParameterDataset:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Code, [Desc]
FROM  TableName
UNION
SELECT 'NULL' AS Code, 'NULL' as [Desc]
```

2nd ParameterDataset:

```
SELECT EventCode
FROM  TableName
UNION
SELECT  'NULL' AS EventCode
```

Main Dataset:

```
Select FieldName1, FieldName2, FieldName3......
From TableNames
Where (isnull(Dispo,'NULL') IN (@Code) )
AND (isnull(Special_Event_Code,'NULL') IN (@EventCode)
```

**Question**: I want to have it as Multi-Select on both parameters and want to select NULL in both parameters if there are any NULL values. When I run the report I am able to get NULL from @EventCode but when I select NULL from 1st parameter and NULL from 2nd parameter nothing is displayed. If I select other value from 1st parameter and NULL from 2nd parameter report is running OK. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to get the `'NULL'` selection to act as ALL? or are you literally looking for `NULL` fields? if the latter, does your table have records where `Dispo` and `Special_Event_Code` is `NULL`? If the former, then you need to tweak your where clause `if @Code = 'NULL' OR  Dispo IN (@Code)`

Comment: maybe you need to use  "or"  instead of  "and"  in your where clause.

Comment: If I select All or just select NULL either way NULL value is ignored in 1st Parameter. Tried if @Code = 'NULL' OR Dispo IN (@Code) it didn't work. I have to use AND to capture NULL values from both columns. Thanks both of you for responding.

Comment: could it be that you dont have records where both fields are null?

Comment: it sure sounds like you have no columns with a NULL value in Dispo.
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TablesNames where Dispo IS NULL.  If your query is more complex than what you've posted, it could be a join operation is eliminating the null values.

Comment: Both table fields has NULL values. I am using LEFT JOIN to join tables.

Comment: Got it. Field Dispo (@Code) is varchar(3) and I was searching NULL which is 4 characters. Thanks! everybody and sorry for the late response.